# chatbot conversational flow with different nodes

Tags: chatbot, watson-assistant

In chatbot conversational flow how and where to define the dependency flow.

should that be handled at the coding level or
can we define in the intents.json file itself.

I have the following intents file

```
intents.json
{
      "tag": "movie_genure",
      "patterns": [
          "list of available movie genures",
          "different genures available"
      ],
      "responses": [
                    "action movies",
                   "adventure movies",
                   "mystery movies"]
}
```

i want the chatbot flow in the following way

```
user: provide the list of available movie genures
bot:   action movies
       adventure movies
       mystery movies

user: list of action movies
bot : movie A
      movie B
      ...
      movie Z
```

Example 1: conversational flow structure

[image]

Example 2: conversational flow in IBM watson
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Watson Assistant, based on your JSON the `patterns` would map to your intents, and the `responses` would map to entities.

In the dialog tree you would look for the intent. For example `#ListActionMovies`.

You would then check to see if an entity was referenced and if not ask the user. For example: `@MovieGenre:mystery`

Your UI is the old version of Watson Assistant. I recommend to switch to the new experience, as it's much easier to use.